# What's the workflow for adding a new required column to a database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, database-design

I installed laravel breeze and I want to use username and password for login instead of email and password.

I added a username field but got an error, the error is pretty clear. I can't add a new required column to an existing DB, I've found two solutions:

1. add a `default('')` attribute to set the username to an empty string for existing records
2. Reset the DB completely.

I went with option A in my current app, my current DB driver is a sqlite so here is how I did it, let me know if there is something wrong here:

```php
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (config('database.default') === 'sqlite') {
                $table->string('username')->default('')->after('id');
            } else {
                $table->string('username')->after('id');
            }
        });
    }
```

I am wondering what would a company with existing users do when they want to introduce a change like this, is it even possible?

Comment: I don't deny that you could do this programmatically, but I always edit the database "directly" by hand. What I mean by "directly" is by using a tool like [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) for MySQL, or in your case [phpLiteAdmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/) for SQLite. Note: I have never used the latter, it's just a example. I think that for simple edits like this it's quicker.

Comment: This edit is far from simple, how would you handle old users having no username and newer users being required to have a username @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Well, the issue with sqlite especially when (editing, adding columns) and running unit test you get plenty of errors like that.. I was doing the same thing as you did, I even create also a [package](https://github.com/PsyLogic/handle-laravel-sqlite-limitation) for that when I was working on a project had similar issues. Summary you can keep your code like that when creating new migrations files

Comment: For the old users you can exec a raw update foe exsiting users by updating their username by email or something similar `username = email where username is null`